# Batch conditional FOR loop nested IF

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a script that parses a text file to identify removable drives by Label. The goal is to create a copy script based on the found drives.

I'm able to parse the file but I can't seem to get the second pair of IF conditions to be true.

I may be misunderstanding how variables are evaluated in each loop of the FOR.

Thoughts appreciated.

**EDIT:** Expanding on the original request for clarity(it was late when I asked) The expanded goal is to identify one or many target drives to copy data from an SD card. Since the drives letter allocations vary from PC to PC and depend on which is plugged in first my idea was to use the labels as somewhat identifiable values and create a simple copy string along the lines of

```
XCOPY SourceDrive\*.jpg DestinationDrive1\<GetDate>\
XCOPY SourceDrive\*.jpg DestinationDrive2\<GetDate>\
```

**End Edit**

```
@echo off
cls
title "Detecting device drive letters..."
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set DestinationDrive1Found=
set DestinationDrive2Found=
set SourceDriveFound=
set SourceDrive=
set DestinationDrive1=
set DestinationDrive2=

echo Detecting device drive letters...

echo list volume > %systemdrive%\ListDrives.tmp
diskpart /s %systemdrive%\ListDrives.tmp > %systemdrive%\CurrentDrives.tmp

echo   Checking drive IDs
FOR /F "skip=7 tokens=2-4" %%a IN (%systemdrive%\CurrentDrives.tmp) DO ( 
set "matchvar=%%c"  
set "comparevar=!matchvar:DRIVE=!" 
IF /I NOT "!comparevar!" == "%%c" IF "!DestinationDrive1Found!" NEQ 1 (
echo Drive %%b was found to be %%c and will be DESTINATION1 
set DestinationDrive1Found=1
set DestinationDrive1=%%b )
IF /I NOT "!comparevar!" == "%%c" IF "!DestinationDrive1Found!" EQU 1 ( echo Drive %%b was found to be %%c and will be DESTINATION2 
set DestinationDrive2Found=1
set DestinationDrive2=%%b )
)
```

File I'm parsing

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.10586

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: NEWGLOOMWIN10

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media           
  Volume 1     E   Macintosh H  HFS    Partition    231 GB  Healthy            
  Volume 2     C   BOOTCAMP     NTFS   Partition    721 GB  Healthy    System  
  Volume 3     F   TEAMXCAMRAX  FAT    Removable   1937 MB  Healthy            
  Volume 4     G   TEAMXDRIVEX  NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy            
  Volume 5     H   TEAMYDRIVEY  NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy
```

Comment: Command __IF__ compares the string left the compare operator with the string right __with double quotes included__. Therefore the condition `IF "!DestinationDrive1Found!" NEQ 1` is always true as the string left of `NEQ` is always with double quotes and the string right of `NEQ` is never with double quotes. So the compared strings are always not equal. The solution is using `"1"` twice on right side of `NEQ` and `EQU`.

Comment: Any chance you could tell us what information you want to produce from the input file? You mention "removable drives" but don't say what information you expect to derive.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Mofi and @Magoo. I've edited the original to expand on the request. However as I wrote this edit I may have actually answered my own question. I believe I can craft what I'm after from the code as it stands. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who responded. Had @Mofi provided an answer I would have marked that response as the answer. In the end the removal of a four quote marks and the addition of an ELSE got me the answer I was looking for.

The script below gives me exactly what I'm after.

```
@echo off
cls
title "Detecting device drive letters..."
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set DestinationDrive1Found=
set DestinationDrive2Found=
set SourceDriveFound=
set SourceDrive=
set DestinationDrive1=
set DestinationDrive2=

echo Detecting device drive letters...

echo list volume > %systemdrive%\ListDrives.tmp
diskpart /s %systemdrive%\ListDrives.tmp > %systemdrive%\CurrentDrives.tmp


echo   Checking drive IDs
FOR /F "skip=7 tokens=2-4" %%a IN (%systemdrive%\CurrentDrives.tmp) DO ( 
set "matchvar=%%c"  
set "comparevar=!matchvar:CAMRA=!" 
IF /I NOT "!comparevar!" == "%%c" (@echo Drive %%b was found to be %%c and will be SOURCE 
set SourceDriveFound=1
set SourceDrive=%%b)
)

echo   Checking drive IDs
FOR /F "skip=7 tokens=2-4" %%a IN (%systemdrive%\CurrentDrives.tmp) DO ( 
set "matchvar=%%c"  
set "comparevar=!matchvar:DRIVE=!" 
IF /I NOT "!comparevar!" == "%%c" IF !DestinationDrive1Found! NEQ 1 (
echo Drive %%b was found to be %%c and will be DESTINATION1 
set DestinationDrive1Found=1
set DestinationDrive1=%%b 
) ELSE ( 
IF /I NOT "!comparevar!" == "%%c" IF !DestinationDrive1Found! EQU 1 ( echo Drive %%b was found to be %%c and will be DESTINATION2 
set DestinationDrive2Found=1
set DestinationDrive2=%%b ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set some variables to the drives allocated to any removable drive with the string `DRIVE` in it's 'label' then the following may provide you with an alternative not requiring elevation.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (`WMIC LogicalDisk Where^
 "DriveType='2' And VolumeName Like '%%DRIVE%%'" Get Name`
) Do For /F %%B In ("%%A") Do Set/A "i+=1"&Call Set "_drv%%i%%=%%B"
Set _drv
Timeout -1
```

**[Edits]** - an example correctly stipulating a fixed drive

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (`WMIC LogicalDisk Where^
 "DriveType='3' And VolumeName Like '%%DRIVE%%'" Get Name`
) Do For /F %%B In ("%%A") Do Set/A "i+=1"&Call Set "_drv%%i%%=%%B"
Set _drv
Timeout -1
```

An example without stipulating the type of drive, *(recommended based on comments)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    `WMIC LogicalDisk Where "VolumeName Like '%%DRIVE%%'" Get Name`
) Do For /F %%B In ("%%A") Do Set/A "i+=1"&Call Set "_drv%%i%%=%%B"
Set _drv
Timeout -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Compo. However I got "Environment variable _drv not defined"

Comment: That means you haven't got a removable drive with a label containing the string DRIVE. That makes sense because your diskpart output indicates that those drives are 465 GB and 931 GB and not removable like the drive indicated as F:. If the drives you are testing with are fixed drives as I expect change `DriveType='2'` to `DriveType='3'` and retry.

Comment: Actually @Compo they are removable, that is, they are USB 3 external drives, just very large. In fact the actual targets are 4 TB USB 3. I'm not sure if that makes a difference but I will try your code with the modification you suggested.

Comment: `DriveType='3'` does work but only for G and H in my example but this is good to know. Thanks for the input.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code then, you will note as I stated, that the DiskPart output only finds one removable drive too and that doesn't contain the string DRIVE either. I would suggest you use the example without stipulating the DriveType, as I have done so in my edit above.

Comment: the only thing wrong with your code is my understanding of it. ;) Thanks for the continued clarification.